# DropDownListFor getting null value and appear ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, null, dropdownlistfor

I attempting to do is passed a viewData from controller to view and display it in drop down list.
I wish to add the selected Id pass into m.movie_type_id.
But I keep on getting ArgumentNullException. Detailed information state that the Value cannot be null.

Below is how I was code and getting error exception.

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.movie_type_id,new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["MT"],"Id","Type")) %>
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult AddMovie()
    {
        ViewData["MT"] = db.MovieType.ToList();
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMovie()
    {
        return view();
    }
```

Current stage is just for testing purpose. Since the error occur during the data pass back to the controller, I wish to fix it before i proceed.

Where did I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that viewdata is filled by some collection and passed into your view like

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  ViewData["MT"] =YourIEnumerableCollection() //Code to get the collection
  return view(model);
}
```

**EDIT**

I think you are getting this in POST scenario, you need to pass the ViewData in POST too like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMovie()
{
    ViewData["SQ"] = db.MovieType.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I had tried your approach, but seem like still the same, unable to get the value which is not null. I edited my post which consist of original code of mine.

Comment: Woah, Thanks bro. It's working now! Thanks a million!